# java Json Map of objects deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, hashmap, deserialization

I have an object i am serializing as a json and back using Jackson. It works fine when the fields are explicitly defined. One of the fields is a Map of <string, Object> as the values of the map can be one of many object types (Enum, concrete class etc). When i deserialize the json, the values in the hashmap seems to lose the type and are all converted to strings. as a result, i am not able to retrieve the data in its original form. Any idea how i can address this?

Thank you in advance

SG

Comment: How does the deserialise step, in isolation, know the types of the values in the map?

Comment: Not really. I assume this is why when we de-serialize it to a concrete object, it will explicitly cast them to the corresponding types. My question was if there is anyway i can indicate to the deserialization process?

Comment: You have to define the map as a class with each key as a field name in order to tie the classes in.